# Merge duplicates in List<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List as shown below.

```
var boxes= new List<Box>(){
new Box(){ Id=1, Name="A1", SrNo="A11"},
new Box(){ Id=2, Name="A1", SrNo="A22"},
new Box(){ Id=3, Name="B1", SrNo="B11"},
new Box(){ Id=4, Name="B1", SrNo="B22"},
new Box(){ Id=5, Name="C1", SrNo="C11"},
new Box(){ Id=6, Name="D1", SrNo="D11"}
}
```

I want to clean the list by merging duplicates by Name so that output looks like this.

```
var boxes = {
        new Box(){ Id=1, Name="A1", SrNo="A11, A22"},
        new Box(){ Id=3, Name="B1", SrNo="B11, B22"},
        new Box(){ Id=5, Name="C1", SrNo="C11"},
        new Box(){ Id=6, Name="D1", SrNo="D11"}
        }
```

I understand that I need to do `GroupBy` but how do I update SrNo so that it appends values from duplicates & remove duplicates rows as well from list ?

Comment: You'll need to `Select` new `Box` objects.

Comment: can you elaborate please ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/491832/1481699

Comment: Was this question answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
var consolidatedBoxes = boxes 
  .GroupBy(b => b.Name)
  .Select(group => 
    new Box { 
       Id = group.First().Id, 
       Name = group.Key.Name, 
       SrNo = string.Join(", " , group.SelectMany(e => e.SrNo).ToList()) })
        .ToList();
```

This is untested, I wrote it on my phone. I think it will do what you want, however.

Comment: It won't work because you're grouping by Id AND Name, rather than just Name.

Comment: Good catch, I think i have edited to correct solution, still untested though

Comment: `FirstOrDefault().Id` is strange. `FirstOrDefault` expresses that a group could be empty, and in that case you'd get a NullReferenceException. `First().Id` seems more appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

For the following result

```
Id   Name SrNo
1    A1   A11,A22
3    B1   B11,B22
5    C1   C11
6    D1   D11
```

Try this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var boxes = new List<Box>(){
            new Box(){ Id=1, Name="A1", SrNo="A11"},
            new Box(){ Id=2, Name="A1", SrNo="A22"},
            new Box(){ Id=3, Name="B1", SrNo="B11"},
            new Box(){ Id=4, Name="B1", SrNo="B22"},
            new Box(){ Id=5, Name="C1", SrNo="C11"},
            new Box(){ Id=6, Name="D1", SrNo="D11"}
        };
        var merged = MergeDuplicates(boxes);

        Console.WriteLine($"{"Id",-4} {"Name",-4} {"SrNo"}");
        foreach (var item in merged)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.Id,-4} {item.Name,-4} {item.SrNo}");
        }
    }

    static List<Box> MergeDuplicates(List<Box> boxes)
    {
        List<Box> result = new List<Box>();
        foreach (var group in boxes.GroupBy((item) => item.Name))
        {
            string name = group.Key;
            var dupes = group.ToArray();
            var first = dupes.First();
            var collect = string.Join(",", dupes.Select((item) => item.SrNo));
            result.Add(new Box() { Id=first.Id, Name=first.Name, SrNo = collect });
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume your Box class is like this.

```
        class Box
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string SrNo { get; set; }


            public override string ToString()
            {
                return $"Id: {Id}\tName: {Name}\t SrNo: {SrNo}";
            }

        }
```

If you want to use linq, you can do it like this:

```
Box[] boxesOrganized =
                boxes
                .GroupBy(grp => grp.Name)    //Create Grouping By Name
                .ToArray()
                .Select(s => new Box()      //Create New Box For Each Grouping                               
            {
                    Id = s.First().Id,      //You Only Want The First Id
                Name = s.First().Name,  //You Only Want the First Name
                SrNo = string.Join(     //Grab The SrNo's And Seperate With A Comma
                        separator: ", ",
                        value: s.Select(s2 => s2.SrNo).ToArray())
                })
                .ToArray();
```

This will get you the output you were looking for:

[image]

Full Code:

```
        public static void GroupMyBoxes()
        {
            List<Box> boxes =
                new List<Box>(){
                new Box(){ Id=1, Name="A1", SrNo="A11"},
                new Box(){ Id=2, Name="A1", SrNo="A22"},
                new Box(){ Id=3, Name="B1", SrNo="B11"},
                new Box(){ Id=4, Name="B1", SrNo="B22"},
                new Box(){ Id=5, Name="C1", SrNo="C11"},
                new Box(){ Id=6, Name="D1", SrNo="D11"}
            };



            Box[] boxesOrganized =
                boxes
                .GroupBy(grp => grp.Name)    //Create Grouping By Name
                .ToArray()
                .Select(s => new Box()      //Create New Box For Each Grouping                               
                {
                    Id = s.First().Id,      //You Only Want The First Id
                    Name = s.First().Name,  //You Only Want the First Name
                    SrNo = string.Join(     //Grab The SrNo's And Seperate With A Comma
                        separator: ", ",
                        value: s.Select(s2 => s2.SrNo).ToArray())
                })
                .ToArray();


            //Print It Out To Verify

            for (int i = 0; i < boxesOrganized.Length; i++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(""
                    + $"{boxesOrganized[i].ToString()}");

            }
        }
```

In my experience I try to avoid Linq, as it can get somewhat difficult to follow.  So I'll leave you with an alternative to keep it simple and have the same result.

```
        public static void GroupWithDictionary() {


            List<Box> boxes =
                new List<Box>(){
                new Box(){ Id=1, Name="A1", SrNo="A11"},
                new Box(){ Id=2, Name="A1", SrNo="A22"},
                new Box(){ Id=3, Name="B1", SrNo="B11"},
                new Box(){ Id=4, Name="B1", SrNo="B22"},
                new Box(){ Id=5, Name="C1", SrNo="C11"},
                new Box(){ Id=6, Name="D1", SrNo="D11"}
            };


            Dictionary<string, List<Box>> boxDictionary =
                new Dictionary<string, List<Box>>();

            Box[][] _boxes = 
                new Box[][] { };    

            foreach (Box _box in boxes)
            {
                if (!boxDictionary.ContainsKey(_box.Name))   //If your box name doesn't exit
                {                                           //Add It To The Dictionary
                    boxDictionary.Add(                      
                        key: _box.Name,
                        value: new List<Box>());            //Initilize A New List For the Box Name

                }   

                boxDictionary[_box.Name].Add(           //Now Add The Box To The List Of Boxes
                    item: _box);                        //With The Given Name
            }


            _boxes =                                    //Dump Into An Array Of Box Arrays
                boxDictionary                           //Or Whatever Suits Your Needs              
                .Select(s => s.Value.ToArray())
                .ToArray();


                                                        //Print It Out To Verify

            for (int i = 0; i < _boxes.Length; i++)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(""
                    + $"Id: {_boxes[i][0].Name}\t"
                    +$"Name: {_boxes[i][0].Name}\t"
                    +$"{string.Join(", ",_boxes[i].Select(s => s.SrNo))}");

            }

               


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

An interesting approach would be to use `Aggregate`.  `GroupBy` is definitely natural here, and the answers using it are correct to do so, but it's useful to understand `Aggregate` because it enables some interesting scenarios for ad hoc transformations.

```
boxes.Aggregate(
    seed: new Dictionary<string, List<Box>>(),
    func: (results, box) => results.GetValueOrDefault(box.Name, new () { box }).Add(box),
    resultSelector: results => results.Select(e => new Box
    {
        Name = e.Key,
        Id = e.First().Id, 
        SrNo = string.Join(", ", e.Select(box => box.SrNo).Distinct())
    })
```